# `(AuthenticationHandler.)Context.Connection.RemoteIPAddress` returns `::ffff:192.168.1.12` on Windows

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-core, ipv6

**What I Do**

I am issuing a HTTP request from a remote client on the same IPv4 local network as a .NET Core ASP server. This server is configured to authenticate requests with a subclass of `AuthenticationHandler` that accesses the remote IP address through `Context.Connection.RemoteIPAddress`.

**What I Expect**

When the application is running on a Unixy system, `Context.Connection.RemoteIPAddress` returns an `IPAddress` that is represented as the expected "192.168.1.12".

**What Happens**

When the application is running on a Windows system, `Context.Connection.RemoteIPAddress` returns an `IPAddress` that is represented as "::ffff:192.168.1.12".

**Problem**

I want to compare the return value of `RemoteIPAddress` to another `IPAddress` value, that, however, is represented as the plain "192.168.1.12". Thus, the two addresses compare as unequal, even though they are (or should be!) the same.

**Non-Solutions**

This is an IPv4-only network, so there's been no point in trying to block IPv6 traffic.

I also don't want to do some sort of fuzzy string comparison; even though it would work and I can't see any problem with it, I have a sense there's a better solution out there.

**Question**

I can see two possible solutions, but I'm not sure how to achieve them:

- There could be a way to ensure that `RemoteIPAddress` returns the remote IP address in the IPv4 shape that I expect.
- It might be possible to always convert all IP addresses to this faux-IPv6 format, and if that conversion is idempotent, it would be a reasonable way to normalise all IP addresses before comparison.

**How would I approach either of these solutions?**

Is one objectively better than the other? (This should be an allowed question, because I'm not asking for personal opinions!)

Comment: When making the connection you have specifically set the parameter to V4.  I think the issue is on following : Context.Connection.RemoteIPAddress.  The end point address must be specified as V4.  Address[0] may be IP6 and you need to use Address[1].              string host = Dns.GetHostName();
            IPAddress[] address = Dns.GetHostAddresses(host);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out option 2 was very simple: simply run `.MapToIPv6()` on both addresses before comparing. I *think* this might be the best solution, for the simple reason that it clearly will not cause any issues when/if this is used with IPv6 addresses too!